# How To Enable Block Editor (Gutenberg) for Existing Post Type via functions.php

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, block-editor

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to enable the block editor for an existing post type in a theme. I'd rather edit this via the functions.php in my child theme rather than edit the theme itself.

This is the code I've come up with in my research, but it doesn't seem to be working using this register_post_type_args filter and the "show_in_rest". Code below:

```
function ux_portfolio_block_editor( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type == "featured_item" ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = array(
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'supports' => array('editor')
        );
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'ux_portfolio_block_editor', 20, 2 );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling the Gutenberg (block) editor for a specific post type requires these criteria:

1. The post type must be *enabled in the REST API* because Gutenberg uses the REST API. And for this, you need to set the `show_in_rest` parameter to `true` when registering the post type — see [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).
2. The post type must *support the editor*, otherwise, the editor won't appear on the post editing screen. And for this, you need to add `editor` to the `supports` parameter (which is an *array*) when registering the post type.

And as you already figured it, you can override (add/edit/remove) a post type's parameters via the [`register_post_type_args` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/). But then, you're overriding the wrong parameter: `rewrite`, which doesn't actually have the `show_in_rest` or `supports` parameter.

And I already stated the correct parameters that should be overridden/set, so here's a working example based on your code — note that it's a better practice to use strict comparison (e.g. `===` for checking equality) and in an expression (or a conditional statement), it's recommended to put the *variable* on the right hand side (e.g. `'value' === $my_var` and not `$my_var === 'value'`):

```php
function ux_portfolio_block_editor( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'featured_item' === $post_type ) {
        // 1. Enable in the REST API.
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;

        // 2. Add the editor support.
        if ( empty( $args['supports'] ) || ! is_array( $args['supports'] ) ) {
            $args['supports'] = [ 'editor' ];
        } elseif ( ! in_array( 'editor', $args['supports'] ) ) {
            $args['supports'][] = 'editor';
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

### How about (custom) taxonomies?

Well, it's similar to post types, except that:

1. Use the [`register_taxonomy_args` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) for overriding the taxonomy's parameters.
2. Taxonomies do not use the `supports` parameter, so to enable the taxonomy (selector) in the block editor (on the post editing screen), you'd only need to set the `show_in_rest` parameter to `true` when registering the taxonomy (see [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)) or when overriding its parameters.

So here's an example for a taxonomy having the slug `block_cat`:

```php
function ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'block_cat' === $taxonomy ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Perfect! That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just discovered that this doesn't enable the category or tags on the WP Block Editor page. I know I need to add:

```'show_in_rest' => true, // Needed for tax to appear in Gutenberg editor```

to the `$args = array (`, but not sure how to add this support via the functions.php to add to this existing post type in the theme. Thoughts? Could I take this same approach? Is there a register_taxonomy_category_args filter?

Comment: Could I add something like this:
```function ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type == "featured_item" ) {
        // First, enable in the REST API.
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_category_args', 'ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Check the revised answer and I'd appreciate an upvote (+1) if the extra info helps... :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, does it work with native wp post types as well? I try it with 'attachment' and yet couldn't make it appear in Gutenberg. It's not getting listed amongst other post types.

Comment: @ViktorBorítás, `attachment` post type is by default enabled for the REST API, so it's also available from within the Gutenberg block editor. I.e. You can use the media endpoint in the REST API to fetch `attachment` posts. Please check the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) for more details.